# How can I export or import my WinSCP sessions?

Tags: windows-registry, winscp

I'd like to transfer all of my WinSCP sessions to a new computer. How can I export them from the registry and re-import them on the other machine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the source computer:

- On WinSCP [Login dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login), use [*Tools > Export/Backup Configuration* command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login#tools).

  *(In case you have an old version of WinSCP, you will find the *Export* button on [Preferences dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_preferences))*

  WinSCP will offer you to store all your configuration to an INI file.

On the destination computer:

- On WinSCP [Login dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login), use [*Tools > Import/Restore Configuration* command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login#tools).

  And select the INI file exported from the source computer.

---

This all is covered in WinSCP FAQ
[How do I transfer my settings to another computer? How do I import/export my settings?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_transfer_config)

The FAQ covers even situation, when your source computer is not working, but you at least have an access to its files.

Answer (score 3):

All credit for this approach goes to m0nhawk's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023920/how-to-export-import-putty-sessions-list

**Note**: Do not replace "Martin Prikryl" in the commands below with your name or any other name. Martin Prikryl is the lead developer of WinSCP and all installations of WinSCP use this registry path.

### Export with PowerShell

All settings:

```
reg export "HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2" ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\winscp.reg")
```

Sessions only:

```
reg export "HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\Sessions" ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\winscp-sessions.reg")
```

### Import with PowerShell

`cd` to the directory containing your `.reg` file and then import.

All settings:

```
reg import winscp.reg
```

Sessions only:

```
reg import winscp-sessions.reg
```

...or, simply double click on a `.reg` file and accept the prompt to import.

Comment: While this indeed works, it's unnecessarily complicated. See my answer.